# Axis discontinuity + enlargelimits not showing axis correctly in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I need to make a y-axis discontinuity, but I also need to configure `enlargelimits=true`. The problem is that the axis is not showing correctly, as the below picture show. If I set `enlargelimits=false`, then the axis discontinuity is correctly done, but the axis values are messed up, as the above picture shows. How can I fix my plots?

[image]

Here is the MWE of the picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=left,
tick align=outside,
axis y discontinuity=crunch, enlargelimits=false
,xtick=data, xlabel=balbalbala, ymin=60, ylabel={balbal [\%]},xlabel style={yshift=-0.3cm}, clip=false, ymax=100]
\addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] coordinates {
(1,68.21)
(2,78.14)
(3,73.57)
(4,87.7)
(5,85.47)
(6,87.36)
(7,89.1)
(8,96.1)
(9,95.7)
(10,91.4)
(11,84.9)
(12,79.69)
};
\node[coordinate,pin=above left:{96.1\%}] at (axis cs:8,96.1) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption[asdf]{RBlalalalala}
\label{lalalala}
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=left,
tick align=outside,
axis y discontinuity=crunch, enlargelimits=true
,xtick=data, xlabel=blablablabla, ymin=400, ymax=1000, clip=false, ylabel=balbal, xlabel style={yshift=-0.3cm}, ylabel style={yshift=0.3cm}]
\addplot[smooth,color=red,mark=x]
coordinates {
(1,944.89)
(2,822.57)
(3,815.4)
(4,707.97)
(5,597.45)
(6,600.83)
(7,568.89)
(8,526.42)
(9,539.7)
(10,573.76)
(11,694.94)
(12,795.55)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption[balbla]{balbalbalblablablalbalb}
\label{balbaba}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems, as if this is not possible. All examples for discontinuities in the pgf manual are using the option `\enlargelimits=false`. However, you can just do it manually. `\enlargelimits=true` increases the limits by 10 % to both sides, so just use `xmin` and `xmax` to specify what ever you need.

Some notes:

- If you leave `xtick=data` away, it looks much better (imho).
- the default for `\enlargelimits=` is `true`. However, the result looks the same when you comment this option. Looks a bit like a bug to me or I am not seeing some documentation...
- I would recommend to insert a `\end{figure}\begin{figure}\centering` between the two figures or to use the package `subcaption` in order to nicely set two images in one `float`.

--

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
,axis x line=bottom,
,axis y line=left,
,tick align=outside,
,axis y discontinuity=crunch
,xmin=0
,xmax=13
,ymin=60
,ymax=100
,enlargelimits=false
%,xtick=data % more beautiful perhaps
,xlabel=balbalbala
,ytickmin=70
,ylabel={balbal in \%}
%,xlabel style={yshift=-0.3cm} % just if you really want it. I would leave it away.
,clip=false
]
\addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] coordinates {%
(1,68.21)
(2,78.14)
(3,73.57)
(4,87.7)
(5,85.47)
(6,87.36)
(7,89.1)
(8,96.1)
(9,95.7)
(10,91.4)
(11,84.9)
(12,79.69)
};
\node[coordinate,pin=above left:{\SI{96.1}{\percent}}] at (axis cs:8,96.1) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{RBlalalalala}
\label{lalalala}
%\vspace{1cm} % just if you really want it. I would leave it away.
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
,axis x line=bottom,
,axis y line=left,
,tick align=outside,
,axis y discontinuity=crunch
,xmin=0
,xmax=13 %enlargelimits=true
,ymin=400
,ymax=1000
,xtick=data
,xlabel=blablablabla
,ytickmin=500
%,clip=false % not needed here
,ylabel=balbal
%,xlabel style={yshift=-0.3cm} % just if you really want it. I would leave it away.
%,ylabel style={yshift=0.3cm} % just if you really want it. I would leave it away.
]
\addplot[smooth,color=red,mark=x] coordinates {%
(1,944.89)
(2,822.57)
(3,815.4)
(4,707.97)
(5,597.45)
(6,600.83)
(7,568.89)
(8,526.42)
(9,539.7)
(10,573.76)
(11,694.94)
(12,795.55)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{balbalbalblablablalbalb}
\label{balbaba}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I also corrected:

- `begin{center}` to `\centering`
- `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}` as requested in the warnings
- `\ymintick` in order to set the first tick above the crunshing.

Comment: Thank you! And it's possible to draw the last value of the y axis below the arrow?

Comment: Which version of the two above do you prefer? Do you want the twelve below the arrow `xmax=12` or the 13?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you, I would like to have the 100 value tick below the arrow head in the y axis (in the first plot). Thanks!

Comment: `ymax=103` looks nice to me. Or instead `enlarge y limits=upper` as suggested by @percusse

Answer (score 2):

You can enlarge only the upper limit of the y axis via `enlarge y limits={upper}` which would use the default value. If that's not enough then you can also add more via value key, e.g., if I replace the

```
enlargelimits=false
```

with

```
enlarge y limits={value=0.5,upper}
```

I get

[image]